# Angular 2 - forcing API return to follow interface types

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, casting

I have this Component :

```
export class myComponent implements OnInit {
    items: Array<ItemInterface>;

    constructor( private itemsService: ItemsService ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.itemsService.getAll()
            .subscribe(
                response => {
                    this.items = response.data;
                    console.log(this.items);
                },
                err => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
    }
}
```

ItemInterface :

```
export interface ItemInterface {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

The API I'm calling returns ids as strings ( like "1" ). I would like to have them as numbers. Is it possible to force the types to cast relatively to the interface definition ? How can I do otherwise ?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use `map` to convert the type. You can use `+` to convert a string to a number. You can specify the type in the map if you want although I believe it is not necessary in most recent versions of typescript as the property's between the interface and the return type match.

```
this.items = response.data
    .map(itm => {
        return {id: +itm.id, name: itm.name} as ItemInterface;
    });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. The API actually returns an array of these objects, how to cast in the full array then ?

Comment: @JeremyBelolo - I am not sure what you are asking or maybe you do not understand what [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) does. Map iterates over an array and returns a custom defined type/value. So in my code above the array in `response.data` is converted to an array of `ItemInterface`.

Comment: Actually it does work perfectly, I was confused. Thanks a lot.